# Shell, echo a file and use as parameter in another program

Tags: shell

I have my database connection string I'm getting from another program, I'd like to use it as a parameter for psql:

Example:

```
http get https://api.heroku.com/apps/foo-app/config-vars Accept:"application/vnd.heroku+json;version=3" | jq '.DATABASE_URL'
```

That returns:

```
postgres://foo:bar@example.com:5432/mydb
```

And I want to be able to basically:

```
http get https://api.heroku.com/apps/foo-app/config-vars Accept:"application/vnd.heroku+json;version=3" | jq '.DATABASE_URL' | psql ?
```

How do I do that, I'd rather avoid evaling the whole string like this:

```
psql $(http get https://api.heroku.com/apps/foo-app/config-vars Accept:"application/vnd.heroku+json;version=3" | jq '.DATABASE_URL')
```

Comment: You can use `"$(< db.txt)"` and treat it like the string contained in `db.txt`. Or, if you don't have Bash, `"$(cat db.txt)"`.

Comment: updated my question ^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to fear `$()`, especially if you double quote it and it doesn't start a command:

```
psql "$(http get https://api.heroku.com/apps/foo-app/config-vars Accept:"application/vnd.heroku+json;version=3" | jq '.DATABASE_URL')"
```

If you don't double quote it, the other side may get your shell to do unwanted word splitting and globbing, but that's it. You're not actually  `eval`ling the string here.

```
str="argument; echo danger" #example wanna-be malicous payload
: $str                      #will not echo danger
eval ": $str"               #this will
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
psql $(cat db.txt)
```

See here:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/app-psql.html

Comment: I updated my example so it's not just printing the file

Comment: @JPSilvashy That does not change anything. Write what ever command you like instead of `cat`. I have no idea what the command `http` does. Maybe you need `curl` instead of `http get`.